# Is this really the shortest way to get the value of a single property object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with a single property, which name I do not know.

Using pure javascript, is the following really the shortest way to get the value of this property?

```
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]
```

Seems like an awful lot. Is there any better alternative? Again **not using any JS libraries**.

Comment: _"Is there any better alternative?"_ - Structure the code in such a way that you _do_ know the name. Or use an array with one element instead of an object with one property.

Comment: What are your criteria for "better"? Less code is not, by itself, a good reason to do anything. If you want robust, maintainable code you would use a for..in loop as suggested by jAndy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your described scenario (having an object with one key, which you don't know), **yes**, that is the shortest way of accessing it.

I don't feel its a lot, given the circumstances by the way. Be aware tho that this will only work on ES5 enabled browsers. Without ES5, it **will** become a lot more:

```
var propName;
for( var prop in obj ) {
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
        propName = prop;
        // break;
    }
}

obj[propName];
```

Comment: +1 for "I don't feel its a lot". Needing to access the sole property of an object, without knowing the property-name and without *wanting* to know it, is not a common use-case. (Also +1 for the correct answer. But the two +1's are the same +1, for a total of +1.)

Comment: +1 , but I feel that the (commented out) `break` statement is redundant. If there's more than one enumerable own property, there's no way of telling if the first one returned is the one the OP wants. Perhaps there should be a counter so an error can be thrown if a second property is enumerated. Just guessing.