# Looping though unique keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json object which I would like to loop through; however each object has a nested object which I can't access through dot notation due to the values being unique.

[image]

```
.__proto__
```

will give me consistent results; however I'd like to pull out the values starting with the "-Jg". Is it possible to do this through a regular expression or another method?

Edit:

I'm looping through the 'javascript object' with angular

```
var lognew = [];

angular.forEach(log, function(value, key) {    
if(value){
  if(value.substr(0,3) !== "-Jg" ){    
  this.push(value);
   }
  }
}, lognew); 

console.log(lognew);
```

This currently returns:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: You appear to be looking at a javascript object, not JSON.

Comment: @MattBurland - Why is that? `{
    "1": {
        "a": "b"
    },
    "2": {
        "c": "d"
    }
}` is valid and not that uncommon from a serialization point of view.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [Is this really the shortest way to get the value of a single property object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13041009/218196).

Comment: @TravisJ: What's your question? Clearly it's an object and not a JSON *string* because the OP is examining it as an object in the debugger.

Comment: @MattBurland - My point was that the object came from JSON, but looking back at the title before your edit, I now see why you made the distinction. So, nevermind :)

Comment: @TravisJ: "My point was that the object came from JSON" which is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I must admit that it peeves me too when people interchange the name [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) when clearly talking about a [`Javascript object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_overview).

Comment: There are many nuanced differences to an object coming from JSON and a plain JavaScript object (hence the use of "json object" in the post). For example, it will never contain functions, is generally expected not to contain circular references (although it can), and rarely contains any prototypes or instance information.

Comment: The [`JSON object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) contains methods for parsing JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and converting values to JSON. It can't be called or constructed, and aside from its two method properties it has no interesting functionality of its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enumerate using `for in` and look at the first 3 characters of the object's key

```
for(var key in jsonObj){
 if( key.substr(0,3) !== "-Jg" ) continue;
 var nestedObject = jsonObj[key];
}
```

*angular edit*

```js
var log = { "1": { "-Jga": "b" }, "2": { "-Jgc": "d" } };

var lognew = [];

angular.forEach(log, function(value, key) {    
 if(key){
  if(key.substr(0,3) !== "-Jg" ){    
   this.push(value);
  }
 }
}, lognew); 

console.log(lognew);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To add some hygiene, you may want to include `if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key))` which will ignore properties not strictly related to the object itself.  Also, you could alternatively get the objects keys `var keys = Object.keys(jsonObj);` and then use that to iterate through the object;

Comment: @lemieuxster - Yes, you could potentially include the `hasOwnProperty` (as is common with `for in`) but since it is already so specific it seemed slightly unnecessary (and unlikely that the object prototype had been modified to include those). Iterating the `keys` and then the object based on the result would work, but it would require slightly more iterations.

Comment: I'm currently returning  TypeError: undefined is not a function, I've added an edit section to the question.

Comment: @byrdr - That is because the value is an object which has no function substr, you should use the key instead.